# iOS universal app links working on simulator, not on real device

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I implemented universal deep links in my React Native app:

Linking.ts:

```js
const config = {
  screens: {
    details: {
      path: "details",
    },
    menu: {
      path: "menu",
    },
    orders: {
      path: "orders",
    },
    share: {
      path: "share",
    },
  },
}

export const linking = {
  prefixes: ["https://getdad.co.uk", "dad://"],
  config,
}
```

apple-app-site-association:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "<TEAMID>.io.feastly.dad",
            "paths": [
                "/details",
                "/menu",
                "/order",
                "/share"
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

They work fine on the Simulator (direct to the correct page, etc), but on a real device they only direct to the app (i.e. they open the app normally, they don't link to a specific screen)

I tested it in multiple ways on the Simulator (e.g safari, address book, from command line)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://` and the bare url to your linking file. `https` goes to safari on the iphone, don't know why, don't care, this works:

```js
export const linking = {
  prefixes: [
    "https://getdad.co.uk",
    "http://getdad.co.uk",
    "getdad.co.uk",
    "dad://",
  ],
  config,
}
```